# SSRS - Sum columns where condition exists

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report, where there are groups (in this case Mills 1-4), each one having a product milled and the tons produced (for example).

I need to add up the 4 groups (ton produced), wherein each group, the product = this.

Like if Mill#1 made product X and Mill#4 also made product X, then I need to add the "tons" produced fields for these two.

If all the Mills made the same product, then the sum would be for "tons produced" for all 4.

Example below:

I would want to add tons produced for the two rows in green where the product = M120

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk8ts.jpg)

["](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4M80.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more info, such as your current report design, a sample of data as it appears in your dataset and the expected outcome. There are too many unknowns at the moment to give a specific answer. Check this link for guidance on asking good questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To make it work the way you want, you'll need to use a Matrix with the columns as your product.

You'll need to add a matrix. Use the MILL for your row column grouping. Use the Product as the Column grouping. Add the TONS as the Data. You can right-click on the TONS and Insert Column -> Inside Group if you also want to add another column - say for the Hours.

Left click on the Tons and you can automatically add the Column Total and Row Total.
For more info, see [MS Docs - Create a Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15).

[image]